# Преобразование DOUBLE в FLOAT без уменьшения диапазона значений

Tags: c++

Считаю функцию `1/sqrt(x)` по методу Ньютона-Рафсона - сейчас посчитано через SSE инструкции, которые оперируют значениями типа `FLOAT`, но встал вопрос увеличения точности и диапазона. Нужен `DOUBLE`.

Вопрос: как преобразовать значения типа `DOUBLE` в тип `FLOAT` при желании оперировать значениями диапазона `[10E50 - 4*10E50]`. То есть нужно как то "увеличить" диапазон флоата для операций с типами M128 и SSE инструкциями.

Comment: Ну, увеличить диапазон `float` - это как в литровую бутылку налить 2 литра... А вот использовать команды для `double` - это другой вопрос. "[SSE может работать с FP32 (float) и FP64(double) IEEE754-числами.](http://www.programmersclub.ru/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-sse/)"